# File not found: project.exe

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have a project in Visual Studio 2010 that requires me to run it as an administrator. I have added the app.manifest file to the project and made the appropriate modifications there. I'm currently running this project under debug configuration. Unfortunately, when I open VS 2010 as an administrator and try to build the project, among other things it complains that it can't find the .exe file for the project (but the .exe file actually exists!).

Furthermore if I run this project as a non-administrator I'm able to build the project. Why is VS claiming that the .exe file does not exist?

Comment: `clean` and `rebuild` your project.

Comment: Did that and I am still getting the error.

Comment: Can you post the actual error message it is giving you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the subst command to create a virtual drive that was the drive for the project. I had to run the command prompt as an administrator and execute the subst command and when I ran VS as an administrator after doing that everything built.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the files in

```
"your_solution_folder"\bin\debug
```

and

```
"your_solution_folder"\obj\debug
```

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting .suo, clean and rebuild solution.